# Automatically posting from Tumblr to a Facebook business page (not a personal Facebook wall)

Tags: facebook, tumblr

It's great that Tumblr allows me to post automatically to my personal Facebook wall, but how do I get it to post automatically to my business Facebook page? Because apps can be allowed only through a personal Facebook account, I'm not sure this is possible. But it sure would be handy!

Answer (score 1):

Try out the following apps:

http://apps.facebook.com/tumblr-feed/

Or else check this page:

http://theimpassionedeye.com/post/1416421032/how-to-publish-your-tumblr-blog-to-a-facebook-fan-page